# sigsegv during __gcc_register_frame (mingw32)

Tags: c++, assembly, dll, x86, mingw32

I try to debug crash (sigsegv especially) of application that uses dynamic libraries (.dll). As I can see it crashes in statically linked part of code in library initialization. GDB shows something similar to (addresses are changing):

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00e41290 in __gcc_register_frame ()
   from library.dll
1: x/5i $pc
=> 0xe41290 <__gcc_register_frame+208>: movl   $0xebc6f0,0x11f2000
   0xe4129a <__gcc_register_frame+218>: mov    $0xebc2b0,%esi
   0xe4129f <__gcc_register_frame+223>: jmp    0xe41222 <__gcc_register_frame+98>
   0xe412a1 <__gcc_register_frame+225>: jmp    0xe412b0 <__gcc_deregister_frame>
```

During the same session I can see that 0x11f2000 is correct part of library.dll

```
    (gdb) info symbol 0x11f2000
deregister_frame_fn in section .data of library.dll
```

Mentioned address space is available from GDB, so setting/reading values is possible:

```
(gdb) print (unsigned char*)0x11f2000
$1 = (unsigned char *) 0x11f2000 <deregister_frame_fn> ""
(gdb) set *(unsigned char*)0x11f2000=1
(gdb) set *(unsigned char*)0x11f2001=2
(gdb) set *(unsigned char*)0x11f2002=3
(gdb) set *(unsigned char*)0x11f2003=4
(gdb) print (unsigned char*)0x11f2000
$2 = (unsigned char *) 0x11f2000 <deregister_frame_fn> "\001\002\003\004"
```

I wonder I'm not able to make short example in cpp, since another library we use in the same application (with the same compiler) is working fine.
The main question is why there may be crash like sigsegv if memory location is available in gdb?
gcc version 5.2.0 (Sourcery CodeBench)

Below backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00e41290 in __gcc_register_frame ()
   from library.dll
#1  0x00eb7afa in __do_global_ctors ()
   from library.dll
#2  0x00e4110b in DllMainCRTStartup@12 ()
   from library.dll
...
```

Comment: You show the symbol is in `.data` which should indeed be writable by default. Note however that gdb doesn't normally care about read-only protection (at least on linux), so that by itself is not a proof that it's writable.

Comment: Is it possible to verify it using gdb and/or any other tool?

Comment: No idea about windows, on linux you'd look into `/proc/<pid>/maps` to verify permissions.

Comment: Trying to write something to .rdata section in gdb, I've got error, so I think it is well defined.